# Suppress output of child process

Tags: c#, .net, linux, windows, console

Let's say we start console application with:

```
public static void StartProcess()
{
    using var next = new Process();
    next.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    next.StartInfo.FileName = "dotnet";
    next.StartInfo.Arguments = "/opt/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.dll";
    next.Start();
}
```

This code leads to double `StandardOutput` and `StandardError`, because parent and child processes will write data to the same terminal. How to supress child process output and/or detach child console?

Of course I can do something like this:

```
public static void StartProcess()
{
    using var next = new Process();
    next.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    next.StartInfo.FileName = "dotnet";
    next.StartInfo.Arguments = "/opt/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.dll";
    next.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    next.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    
    next.Start();
    next.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(Stream.Null);
    next.StandardError.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(Stream.Null);
}
```

As far as I understand this will work until parent process is alive, but what if child process will work longer than parent one? Need some stable, cross-platform solution.

Comment: Generally spawning `$SHELL "command > nul"` will do it.  This is one syntax that all common shells share.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I am asking how to do this programmatically and cross-platform with pure C#

Comment: So `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SHELL")` ?

Answer (score 2):

Adding `StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true` fixed it for me.

Well, almost... Starting the process still spits out a newline onto the Linux console, but no other output.